# Add headers to mpegts.js request

Tags: javascript, vue.js, video, ffmpeg

I'm very new in web technologies. I have a .ts video accessed by my api and for security reason I need to add 'x-access-token' to my request, but really do not how. Maybe you know?

```
play(){
  if (mpegts.getFeatureList().mseLivePlayback) {
    var videoElement = document.getElementById('video-js-node');
    var player = mpegts.createPlayer({
       type: 'm2ts',
       isLive: true,
       headers: {'x-access-token': localStorage.getItem('data')},
       url: `/my/api/${record}`,
     });
     player.attachMediaElement(videoElement);
     player.load();
     player.play();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've read a documentation (https://github.com/xqq/mpegts.js/blob/master/docs/api.md) and understand my mistake. The code should look like this:

```
play(){
  if (mpegts.getFeatureList().mseLivePlayback) {
    var videoElement = document.getElementById('video-js-node');
    var player = mpegts.createPlayer(
       //MediaDataSource
       {
          type: 'm2ts',
          isLive: true,
          url: `/my/api/${record}`,
       },
       //config
       {
        headers: {
           'x-access-token': localStorage.getItem('data')
       }
    );
    player.attachMediaElement(videoElement);
    player.load();
    player.play();
  }
}
```